# Gain of a feedback amplifier with base to collector resistor

Tags: transistors, analog, small-signal, negative-feedback, voltage-amplification

I'm able to solve this problem using the concept of Miller resisitance however I'm having an issue solving this problem using the concept of feedback amplifiers. Can someone help me solve this problem using the concept of feedback amplifiers ? This is a question asked in a competitive exam GATE in India and is no homework problem. Only one among the 4 options is the correct answer.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't homework, it is an **EXAM** question.

Comment: This is an exam conducted in national level long back and also official key for the exam is released therby I know the answer as 10. I'm using the question only to build my concepts in bjt amplifiers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework without an attempt at a solution is off topic

Answer (score 2):

[ this answer, tho accepted, needs additional review ]
[looks like the EXAM question is primarily --- do you understand bipolar biasing? --- and a smidgeon of feedback theory. ]

The standard feedback formula

Transfer function = G / (1 + G*H)

works just fine.

You have 4 cases of G: 200, 100, 20, 10

And your H (perturb the output, and 1/11 is the feedback ratio) is 1/11.

Thus you have

200 / 1 + 200/11

100 / 1 + 100/11

20  / 1 +  20/11

10  / 1 +  10/11

==========   first pass of linearized model =======

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnChuO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Only if 'gm' [ delta_amps_out / delta_volts_in ] becomes infinite to make open-loop-gain become infinite, and if 'Rin' [ beta / gm ] becomes infinite to make the feedback division defined only by 10K an d100K, does the "10" become the answer.

We have to reverse-engineer all the port-definitions of the series-shunt model, as suggested by the wiki article.

Comment: Those are the final options not gain without feedback Av . Only one among the 4 options is the correct answer

Comment: Then you need to decide what is the operating point. Given the VDD is the very special 13.7 volts, subtracting 0.7 for Vbe, and 1v Vbc, we have exactly 12 volts across the 12Kohm resistor, thus 1mA Ic. Which makes gm = 1/26 ohms at room temperature. The openloop (base to collector) gain is 12,000/26 or about 400X. Since 400X is not one of the choices......

Comment: Yeah , the correct option is 10. I did try the method you mentioned . I was able to get the answer using Miller resistance method but not using feedback amplifier analysis. The answer however is 10.

Comment: Judging from the ratios, the gain is 100K / 10K = 10, +- some error set by the openloop gain.

Comment: How can it be 10 using feedback amplifier analysis ?

Comment: There are 4 topologies: series-series, series-shunt, shunt-series, shunt-shunt. Which is this? (the feedback is shunting the output, the feedback is in series with the input). Here is very good Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-feedback_amplifier

Comment: Ahhhh if the input were the emitter (non-inverting input), then the gain would be 11X. And the Wikipedia article does bring up this case.

Comment: The "standard feedback formula" as given at the beginning does NOT apply here!! It neglects the input damping factor . More than that, it is wrong to assume that G is the closed-lop gain. In this formula, the open-loop gain must a´pperar only! Hence, the whole answer cannot help at all.

Comment: If very little signal current flows thru the R4, the 2,600 ohm resistor, then the AC base voltage is very accurate. Can we compute that?

Answer (score 2):

The **feedback formula** to be applied is (remember the inverting opamp gain formula)

**Av=-AoHf/(1+AoHr)**

with Ao=open-loop gain;

Hf=forward damping **Hf=RB/(RB+R1)**;

Hr=return damping (feedback factor) **Hr=R1/(R1+RB)**.

We have R1=10k and RB=100k.

For finding the open-loop gain Ao we need the DC collector current Ic which can be found (using VBE=0.7V):

**Ic=1mA**; and **gm=Ic/Vt=0.04mA/V** ; and **Ao=-gmRc=-480**.

Inserting these values into the gain formula for Av we arrive at app. **Av=-10**.

(Note: We have not used the Miller effect because the factors Hf is defined for zero output).

**EDIT/UPDATE**:

In the above calculation, the finite input impedance at the base node was - as a first step - neglected. The value of r,in is to be caculated at first:

r,in=beta/gm=100/0.04=2.5 kohms.

In this case, we have Hf=0.2 and Hr=0.02.

Aplying the given feedback formula, the resulting closed-loop gain is app Av=-9.1.

Comment: The formula is giving current answer. Could you please tell me how you arrived at the formula ?

Comment: It is the well-known formula (introduced by H. Black) for systems with negative feedback - and can be found in all textbooks dealing with feedback (in particular, control system articles/books).

Comment: Sir, is the formula valid for other feedback configurations as well ? If you could recommend a link with considerable problem set it would be highly helpful .

Comment: I feel that you're linking it to A/1+AB formula in control system and here B= Hr and Hf is some voltage divider model. But how can we derive at this formula for the feedback amplifier ?

Comment: Yes - an amplifier with negative feedback can be treated as a special control system. Remember the classical gain formulas for operational amplifiers. Note: In my contribution, I have neglected (as it is normal for opamps) the influence of a finite input resistance of the active device. In an update I will give the results for a finite input resistance r,in at the base.

Comment: Sir , Im comfortable finding the input resistance but I'm not able to link it to the concept of feedback amplifiers . Request you to please update or suggest a link from where I can study the derivation of the concept that you have applied. Thank you for the concept, you were able to generate high levels of interest in the question with the way you explained.

Comment: The forward damping factor Hf is defined as the portion of the input signal that arrives directly at the input of the amplifier (base node) if the output signal is set to zero! Hence, we have a simple voltage divider with 100k||r,in. Similarly, the feedback factor Hr is the portion of the ouput signal that appears at the base node if we set the input signal to zero. Now we have another voltage divider with R1||r,in.

Comment: Sir, the formula now has become very clear for me now . I have been working hard on the problem from the moment you gave the solution. I did draw the small signal model and derived the exact voltage gain equation for the problem after writing a few kvl equations and then doing the necessary substitions. However from the exact answer Im not able to reach the feedback amplifier formula that you mentioned . Could you please help with derivation of the formula -Ao.Hf/(1+Ao.Hr). Is this formula valid for any feedback amplifier ? Is this like your own patended formula sir?

Comment: Sir,I also tried another problem of the same model and understood the concept that approximate voltage gain will be -(RB/R1) when I+AO.Hr is approximated to Ao.Hr , so the approx answer here is -(RB/R1). I'm in all the cases stuck at the derivation of the formula.

Comment: As I have mentioned, the formula is the classic equation for any feedback system. There are many internet contributions dealing with this subject. See for instance here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/systems/feedback-systems.html

Comment: Sir, here all cases of  sampling and mixing alongwith  the 4 types of feedback amplifiers is mentioned. I was looking for the derivation of the formula you mentioned -Ao.Hf/(1+Ao.Hr)

Comment: Sir, I just derived the formula you mentioned. However the approximate answer using the formula is -7.55 and not -9.1. Could you please verify ?

Comment: What are your values for Ao, Hf and Hr ?

Comment: You were totally right sir , I had made a calculation error. Now the concept is very clear . I derived the formula you mentioned and calculated the answer , also I tried solving it using the small signal analysis and verfied the answer as well. Thanks a lot sir for the help .